# Python3 - Encrypting and decrypting an image (Fernet) Issue

Tags: python, image, encryption, cryptography

Good day,

I am doing an assignment for cryptography. It's an easy task I need to take any image, turn it into HEX, encrypt it and then decrypt it.

As I am working in Python and there was no specific encryption method in the task I just use Fernet.

I have an encryptor and decryptor scripts.

Encryption seems to be working because as a test I create a txt document with original HEX and after decryption the program states that original HEX and decrypted one are the same, however the decrypted image is not loading.

Could anyone help out a newbie?

Encryptor:

```
import binascii
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

img = 'panda.png'
with open(img, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
hexValue = binascii.hexlify(content)
key = Fernet.generate_key()

with open('info/key.txt', mode='w+') as keyValue:
    keyValue.write(key)
    keyValue.seek(0)

f = Fernet(key)
encHexVal = f.encrypt(hexValue) 

with open('info/encryptedHex.txt', mode='w+') as hexValueFile:
    hexValueFile.write(encHexVal)
    hexValueFile.seek(0)
a = f.decrypt(encHexVal)

with open('info/realValue.txt', mode='w+') as writeHex:
    originalHex = writeHex.write(hexValue)

with open('info/realValue.txt', mode='r') as reading:
    realValue = reading.read()
if realValue == a:
    print("We're good to go!")
else:
    print("Oops something went wrong. Check the source code.")
```

Decryptor:

```
import binascii
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

with open('info/key.txt', mode='rb') as keyValue:
    key = keyValue.read()
    f = Fernet(key)
with open('info/encryptedHex.txt', mode='rb') as imageHexValue:
    hexValue = imageHexValue.read()
a = f.decrypt(hexValue)
with open('info/realValue.txt', mode='r') as compare:
    realContents = compare.read()

print("Small test in safe environment...")
if realContents == a:
    print("All good!")
else:
    print("Something is wrong...")
data = a.encode()
data = data.strip()
data = data.replace(' ', '')
data = data.replace('\n', '')
with open('newImage.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

I am using a random image from the internet of Po from Kung Fu Panda:
[image: Po from Kung Fu Panda]

Comment: In Encrypter, open('info/key.txt', mode='w+') is wrong... it needs to open in binary mode.

Comment: Should it be encrypt and then turn to HEX? Do it the other way and you end up with binary, not text.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? There are several bytes/str problems in the code.

Comment: @tdelaney I fixed it by writing "wb+" but the image is still not loading. I am using python 3. 
It should first turn it into HEX and then encrypt the HEX value itself.

Comment: In that case, 'info/encryptedHex.txt' is really binary. The core problem is that you don't unhexlify the decrypted data before saving newImage.png.

Comment: @tdelaney You were right. I am sorry I don't know how such a simple thing slipped through me. Anyway, thank you very much for your help and have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle problem is that although you hexlify then encrypt in the encryptor you don't unhexlify after decrypting in the decryptor. Its far more common to do things the other way, encrypt then hexlify so that the encrypted binary can be stored in regular text files or sent via http.

You have several problems with trying to write `bytes` objects to files open in text. I fixed those along the way. But it does leave me puzzled why a file called 'info/encryptedHex.txt' would be binary.

Encryptor

```
import binascii
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# Generate keyfile
#
# TODO: Overwrites key file on each run, invalidating previous
# saves. You could do `if not os.path.exists('info/key.txt'):`
key = Fernet.generate_key()
with open('info/key.txt', mode='wb') as keyValue:
    keyValue.write(key)

# Encrypt image
img = 'panda.png'
with open(img, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
hexValue = binascii.hexlify(content)

f = Fernet(key)
encHexVal = f.encrypt(hexValue) 

with open('info/encryptedHex.txt', mode='wb') as hexValueFile:
    hexValueFile.write(encHexVal)

# Verification checks
a = f.decrypt(encHexVal)

# hexed bytes is same encoding as 'ascii'
with open('info/realValue.txt', mode='wb') as writeHex:
    originalHex = writeHex.write(hexValue)

with open('info/realValue.txt', mode='r', encoding='ascii') as reading:
    realValue = reading.read()
if realValue == a.decode('ascii'):
    print("We're good to go!")
else:
    print("Oops something went wrong. Check the source code.")
```

Decryptor

```
import binascii
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

# Generate keyfile
#
# TODO: Overwrites key file on each run, invalidating previous
# saves. You could do `if not os.path.exists('info/key.txt'):`
key = Fernet.generate_key()
with open('info/key.txt', mode='wb') as keyValue:
    keyValue.write(key)

# Encrypt image
img = 'panda.png'
with open(img, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
hexValue = binascii.hexlify(content)

f = Fernet(key)
encHexVal = f.encrypt(hexValue) 

with open('info/encryptedHex.txt', mode='wb') as hexValueFile:
    hexValueFile.write(encHexVal)

# Verification checks
a = f.decrypt(encHexVal)

# hexed bytes is same encoding as 'ascii'
with open('info/realValue.txt', mode='wb') as writeHex:
    originalHex = writeHex.write(hexValue)

with open('info/realValue.txt', mode='r', encoding='ascii') as reading:
    realValue = reading.read()
if realValue == a.decode('ascii'):
    print("We're good to go!")
else:
    print("Oops something went wrong. Check the source code.")
(base) td@timpad:~/dev/SO/Encrypting and decrypting in image$ cat de.py
import binascii
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

with open('info/key.txt', mode='rb') as keyValue:
    key = keyValue.read()
    f = Fernet(key)
with open('info/encryptedHex.txt', mode='rb') as imageHexValue:
    encHexValue = imageHexValue.read()
hexValue = f.decrypt(encHexValue)
binValue = binascii.unhexlify(hexValue)

with open('info/realValue.txt', mode='rb') as compare:
    realContents = compare.read()

print("Small test in safe environment...")
if realContents == hexValue:
    print("All good!")
else:
    print("Something is wrong...")
with open('newImage.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(binValue)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for elaborate answer again. It was hexlify and I fixed it by adding

test1 = binascii.unhexlify(data)

and writing unhexlified(?) text into the file. 

Thank you again!

I am a beginner so I make some stupid mistakes all the time.